# Implementing class with unique identification number

Tags: java

I have to make a class that has int member which is unique for every object of that class. So:

```
public class Cls {
    private int id;
    public Cls(){id = unique number;}
}
```

So when I make x number of `Cls` objects, I must be sure that no classes have the same id. But I want to avoid making global variable in main, and setting id one by one. If it is possible it would be great if id can be set in the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hold a `static` value containing the last value you used and always increment it every time you use it. An `AtomicInteger` is excellent for this because it is thread safe and does not require locks if used in a multi-thread environment.

```
public class Cls {
    // The last id I used.
    private static final AtomicInteger nextId = new AtomicInteger();
    // My id
    private final int id = nextId.getAndIncrement();

    public Cls() {
    }
}
```

Comment: It does introduce memory barrier.

Answer (score 4):

The [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class provides a simple means for generating unique ids.

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class GenerateUUID {

  public static final void main(String... aArgs){
    UUID uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID();
    log("unique ID: " + uniqueID);
  }

  private static void log(Object aObject){
    System.out.println( String.valueOf(aObject) );
  }
}
```

[read more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use a static variable and increment it:

```
public class Cls {

    private static int count = 0;
    private int id;

    public Cls() { 
        id = count;
        count++;
    }
}
```

The first object will have `id = 0`, the second one will have `id = 1`, etc.

**Limitation**: This method is the simplest one, but it won't work if you want to have an application that uses many threads.

---

## Multithreading

If you are in a multithreading context, you'll need to be sure that you have some expected results. Some possible methods:

1) Use a class from `java.util.concurrent.atomic` ( E.g. `AtomicInteger` ) (according to OldCurmudgeon)

2) Instead of `count++`, call a synchronized method that has the following structure:

```
public static synchronized void incrementCount() {
    count++; 
}
```

3) Use an additional object for synchronization:

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();
```

and then use it to synchronize the increment operation:

```
public void increment() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can, but such code will fail in a multithreaded environment. You are not guaranteed that all instances of Cls has unique ids.

Comment: I also added details about the multithreading context. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a surrounding structure which manages the uniqueness of that index or use a UUID. A UUID still has a very slight chance of collision, but this shouldn't be a problem with small amountd of data.

Comment: How do you define "small"?

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates) for numbers

Comment: I asked how *you* define small.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

```
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a numeric uid? Also, are you looking for unique across a jvm or unique across all runs of the app? Are you looking for unique only for live objects or across the entire run of the app?

For a limited set of answers (no, across jvm only, only for live objects), simplest would be to use the Object id of the object. But this is not numeric, and can be reused after an object dies. However you get gaurenteed uniqueness for free.